# Using a Webview in a splitview controller

Tags: uiwebview, ios7

I'm having trouble displaying content properly in a splitview application. In the detail view I have a webview and I'm loading locally saved html files. However the files don't display properly - they are slightly zoomed in and missing detail on the left and right. Double taping them zooms them out and they display correctly. I have scaletofitpages=YES set.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
Well, if i'm understanding  you correctly, you can use auto layout.. it will fit your content from left and right.

to set the font size you must edit your html content add "css style" to them...

// Get result into string format
    NSString *htmlData = [objSQLiteProtocol getDatabaseResults:fileNameToRead];

    // reduce the size of font to set in iPad
    htmlData = [htmlData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"25pt" withString:@"12pt"];

    [moreWebView loadHTMLString:htmlData baseURL:nil];

    moreWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```